# Passing Parameters to Android Configuration and Send it to a Server

Tags: php, android

I would like to pass a parameter programmatically to the php configuration file.

The code in DbOperations.php:

```
function getName() {
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT name,teamaffiliation 
    as team  FROM heroes WHERE id = 6");

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $team);

    $heroes = array(); 

    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $hero  = array();
        $hero['name'] = $name; 
        $hero['team'] = $team;
        array_push($heroes, $hero); 
    }

    return $heroes; 
}
```

And this is my api.php:

```
case 'getname':
    $db = new DbOperation();
    $response['error'] = false; 
    $response['message'] = 'Request successfully completed';
    $response['heroes'] = $db->getname();
    break;
```

I would like to pass a value for the ID (`id = x`) programmatically, please help me to achieve this.

Also, I need to pass the parameter from android to php. I tried the following code, but this is also not working.

```
private void retrive() {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("id", "5");
    PerformNetworkRequest request = new PerformNetworkRequest(Api.URL_READ_NAME, params, CODE_POST_REQUEST);
    request.execute();
}
```

Comment: pass id in url or in a param by android then get that in your API by `$_GET` or `$_POST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a RESTful API you could pass in the ID via GET, so your URL could look like `/api.php?id=1`.

Then in `api.php` you can access that variable using `$_GET['id'];` and pass it into your `getname` function.

Eg.

```
case 'getname':
    $db = new DbOperation();
    $response['error'] = false; 
    $response['message'] = 'Request successfully completed';
   $response['heroes'] = $db->getname($_GET['id']);
break;
```

Then in your function you can change `id = 6` to `id = ?` and bind the parameter (`?`) to the variable `$id` using `$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);` The `i` here means that the parameter is an integer, other options are:

- i - integer
- d - double (float)
- s - string
- b - BLOB

Eg:

```
function getName($id){
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT name, teamaffiliation 
    as team  FROM heroes WHERE id = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $team);

    $heroes = array(); 

    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $hero  = array();

        $hero['name'] = $name; 
        $hero['team'] = $team; 


        array_push($heroes, $hero); 
    }

    return $heroes; 
}
```

Comment: Can you help me to pass the same parameter from android to php? i have tried this  ` private void retrive() {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("id", "5");
       PerformNetworkRequest request = new PerformNetworkRequest(Api.URL_READ_NAME, params, CODE_POST_REQUEST);

       //request.execute();

        //refreshHeroList();








        // editText1.setText("X");


    }`